# Facebook access token AppId|AppSecret stop working?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

in a project i have i used this call to retrieve info about a photo by id

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://graph.facebook.com/".$idPost."?fields=likes,comments,shares,created_time&access_token=AppId|AppSecret");
```

It doesn't work anymore but i can't find mention about the "deprecation" of this access token type. I have tried also

```
https://graph.facebook.com/".$idPost."/likes?access_token=AppId|AppSecret
```

This last call return to me an empty json

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

I can see data only if i change a token with on of the token i can take from the Debugger tool. My question is:
i can't use anymore the access token AppId/AppSecret ? There's an alternative without use the php/JavaScript Facebook framework?

EDIT

the $idPost variable store the value returned by this publishing method:

```
function fb_publish_Photo(imagelink){


             var wallPost = {
                message: "Test to post a photo",
                link:imagelink,
                picture:imagelink
              };
              FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', wallPost , function(response) {
                if (!response || response.error) {

                  alert('Failure! ' + response + ' You may logout once and try again');
                } else {
                  alert('Success! Post ID: ' + response.id);
                  var PostId=response.id;
                  if(response.id!=null && response.id!=''){


                    });
                  }
                }

              });
    }
```

Comment: what is the post id? is it a page post?

Comment: the id of posted photo

Comment: which id exactly? please add the link.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you don´t have sufficient permissions to get the data. If it´s about a photo on a User Profile, you can´t use an App Token. You would need a User Token with the `user_posts` permission. If it´s a photo of a Page, the Page may be restricted by age or location. In that case, you would need to use a User Token of someone who is allowed to see the photo.

More information about Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: i'm a little bit confused, my curl call seems to work fine until some weeks ago... Anyway i have tried to use a test-user with all permission setted and the graph-explorer to get a token and it still doesn't work. It isn't a page photo, it's a photo posted on a user wall

Comment: well, read my answer. you can´t get user photos with only an app access token. should never have worked actually.